# Adding header file as a source in CMakeLists.txt

Tags: cmake

Is it possible to achieve the following in cmake?

```
xxfile:     afile.o bfile.o
            $(CC) $(CFLAGS) afile.o bfile.o $(libpath) -labc -o dfile

afile.o:   cfile.h
```

Any suggestions please.

Comment: This only adds **dependency** between object file and header file, doesn't it? If so, just list header file among sources in `add_executable()` call. Note, that is only needed if you have `add_custom_command` which *OUTPUT* given file, or if sources doesn't use given header. Otherwise, CMake is smart enough to recompile the source if header included by it has been changed.

Comment: If you have `add_custom_command`, then you can probably put the header in the `DEPENDS` argument too.